# NestJS/TypeORM: Cannot set property metadata of #<Repository> which has only a getter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I try to run my nestjstutorial app, the below error is showing. My backend is connected to a PostgreSQL db.

> TypeError: Cannot set property metadata of # which has only a getter
> at EntityManager.getCustomRepository (D:\Ganesh\MyDrive\nestjs\nestjs_tutorial\nestjsturorial\src\entity-manager\EntityManager.ts:1404:59)
> at DataSource.getCustomRepository (D:\Ganesh\MyDrive\nestjs\nestjs_tutorial\nestjsturorial\src\data-source\DataSource.ts:465:29)
> at InstanceWrapper.useFactory [as metatype] (D:\Ganesh\MyDrive\nestjs\nestjs_tutorial\nestjsturorial\node_modules@nestjs\typeorm\dist\typeorm.providers.js:13:35)
> at Injector.instantiateClass (D:\Ganesh\MyDrive\nestjs\nestjs_tutorial\nestjsturorial\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:333:55)
> at callback (D:\Ganesh\MyDrive\nestjs\nestjs_tutorial\nestjsturorial\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:48:41)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (D:\Ganesh\MyDrive\nestjs\nestjs_tutorial\nestjsturorial\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:122:24)
> at Injector.loadInstance (D:\Ganesh\MyDrive\nestjs\nestjs_tutorial\nestjsturorial\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:52:9)
> at Injector.loadProvider (D:\Ganesh\MyDrive\nestjs\nestjs_tutorial\nestjsturorial\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:74:9)
> at Injector.lookupComponentInImports (D:\Ganesh\MyDrive\nestjs\nestjs_tutorial\nestjsturorial\node_modules@nestjs\core\injector\injector.js:265:17)

My code looks like this:

**app.module**

```
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { AppController } from './app.controller';
    import { AppService } from './app.service';
    import { UserController } from './user/user.controller';
    import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
    import { UserService } from './user/user.services';
    import { QuizModule } from './modules/quiz/quiz.module';
    //import { QuizController } from './modules/quiz/quiz.controller';
    //import { QuizService } from './modules/quiz/quiz.services';
    import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
    import { typeOrmConfig } from './config/typeorm.config';
    //import { QuizRepository } from './modules/quiz/quiz.repository';
    
    @Module({
      imports: [UserModule, QuizModule, TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig)],
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [AppService],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

**quiz.controller**

```
    import {
      Body,
      Controller,
      Get,
      HttpCode,
      Post,
      UsePipes,
      ValidationPipe,
    } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { QuizService } from './quiz.services';
    import { CreateQuizDto } from '../dto/CreateQuiz.dto';
    
    @Controller('quiz')
    export class QuizController {
      constructor(private readonly quizService: QuizService) {}
    
      @Get('/')
      getAllQuiz() {
        return this.quizService.getAllQuiz();
      }
    
      @Post('/create')
      @HttpCode(200)
      @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
      async createQuiz(@Body() quizData: CreateQuizDto) {
        return await this.quizService.createNewQuiz(quizData);
      }
    }
```

**quiz.services**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
    import { QuizRepository } from './quiz.repository';
    import { CreateQuizDto } from '../dto/CreateQuiz.dto';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class QuizService {
      constructor(
        @InjectRepository(QuizRepository) private quizRepository: QuizRepository,
      ) {}
    
      getAllQuiz() {
        return [1, 2, 'from service', 3];
      }
      async createNewQuiz(quiz: CreateQuizDto) {
        return await this.quizRepository.save(quiz);
      }
    }
```

**quiz.module**

```
    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
    import { QuizController } from './quiz.controller';
    import { QuizService } from './quiz.services';
    import { QuizRepository } from './quiz.repository';
    
    @Module({
      controllers: [QuizController],
      imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([QuizRepository])],
      providers: [QuizService],
    })
    export class QuizModule {}
```

**quiz.repository**

```
    import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
    import { Quiz } from './quiz.entity';
    
    @EntityRepository(Quiz)
    export class QuizRepository extends Repository<Quiz> {
      //<Quiz> means Quiz module
    }
```

**typeorm.config**

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

    export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'postgres',
      password: '123456',
      database: 'quiz',
      entities: [__dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: true,
    };
```

**dto**

```
import { isNotEmpty, IsNotEmpty, Length } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateQuizDto {
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'Title mandatory' })
  @Length(3, 255)
  title: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Length(3)
  description: string;
}
```

**entity**

```
import { BaseEntity, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('quizes')
export class Quiz extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    comment: 'The quiz unique identifier',
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  title: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'text',
  })
  description: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  usernmae: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'date',
  })
  createddate: Date;

  @Column({
    type: 'boolean',
    default: 1,
  })
  isActive: boolean;
}
```

Somebody know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem and the solution was the following: you have to make sure that the version of nestjs/typeorm and typeorm are compatible in my case I had version of nestjs/typeorm 8.0.3 and typeorm 0.3.6 , these versions are not compatible , version 8.0.3 of nest is compatible with version 0.2.34. When I changed my typeorm version to 0.2.34 it compiled successfully.

[package.json version image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovl0d.png)

Comment: this solution worked for me as well, I also had exact problem.

Comment: It also solved other issues I was experiencing

Answer (score 1):

Which version of **@nestjs/typeorm** and **typeorm** are you using? If you are using typeorm > 0.3 this is a known issue and using the required typeorm will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem, with @nestjs/typeorm v8.1.4 and TypeORM 0.3.12

However, since [v8.1.0](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/releases/tag/8.1.0), @nestjs/typeorm is compatible with TypeORM 0.3.

Therefore, it should be working without downgrading. Still, doing custom repositories with TypeORM 0.3 is quite different.

I was able to make the necessary changes by following [this article](https://tech.durgadas.in/creating-and-using-custom-repositories-in-nestjs-with-typeorm-0-3-c7ac9548ad99).

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `CustomRepository` you should remove the `InjectRepository` decorator and simply let `NestJS` inject it.

**quiz.service**

```js
constructor(
    private quizRepository: QuizRepository,
) {}
```

you haven't posted your `typeorm.config` file so make sure to declare `Quiz` entity so `TypeORM` will know where to look for it.

Comment: Tried remove InjectRepository still error remains the same. Also edited the posted with typeorm.config