# How do I resolve EntityMetadataNotFoundError in NestJS with TypeORM?

Tags: database, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

When i run my code i get this typeorm error,

```
[error] 33748   - 06/02/2023, 10:13:49  uncaughtException: No metadata for "EmployeePermission" was found.
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "EmployeePermission" was found.
```

I have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72020892/14316397).

But it is not working sometimes.

What do i have to do to solve this problem?